# Embedded a Lua interactive prompt window in C#

Tags: c#, .net, shell, lua, interactive

I tried to provide some script features in my C# App. 
   After some searches, The Lua and LuaInterface looks like a reasonable way to do it.
   By embedding a Lua VM in my C# code, I can load a Lua script and process methods 
   defined in the C# class without any problems.

However, I wonder is there a way to not only execute a lua script file in 
   my c# program, but also to have a lua interactive prompt in my program? 
   Thus I can type commands and see the returns immediately.

Any hint about where I should start to work on it will be very helpful!

Best Regards

Comment: (more sophisticated shells: [Is there a lua enhanced interactive shell like python with IPython? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615456/is-there-a-lua-enhanced-interactive-shell-like-python-with-ipython))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua's `debug` module contains a very basic interactive console: `debug.debug()` (the Lua manual suggests [this module should be used only for debugging](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.9)).

If that doesn't meet your needs, it's easy enough to implement one yourself. If you were to write it in Lua itself, the absolute bare bones console would be:

```
while true do
   io.write("> ")
   loadstring(io.read())()
end
```

That'll crash on either a syntax or runtime error. A slightly less minimal version, which captures (and ignores) errors:

```
while true do
   io.write("> ")
   local line = io.read()
   if not line then break end -- quit on EOF?
   local chunk = loadstring(line)
   if chunk then
      pcall(chunk)
   end
end
```

This could be enhanced by displaying syntax errors (second return value from `loadstring` on failure), runtime errors (second return value from `pcall` on failure), return values from evaluated code ([2..N] return values from `pcall` on success), etc.

If you want to get *really* fancy, you can allow people to enter multi-line statements. Look at `src/lua.c` in the source distro to see how this is done.

Comment: It is a bad idea to use anything from `debug` module not for debugging. I suggest to remove the first paragraph from this answer.

Comment: The OP didn't say what he wanted the console for. It may very well *be* for debugging, in which case the information is useful. A disclaimer would be more appropriate than removal. I'll add that now.