# Is there a lua enhanced interactive shell like python with IPython?

Tags: python, shell, lua, ipython

I was using IPython (qtconsole&notebook) to learn python and I love that very much.

Now I'm learning lua and using *lua for windows* on win7. The attached editor(or IDE?) `SciTE` is a nice editor, while I'd also like to know if there is a good *interactive shell*. The current shell is a bit basic and hard to use.

I hope there is one with at least:

1. tab completion
2. quick reference to docs

etc.

Comment: why vote to close??? your vote helps nobody! I don't think this question attracts opinionated answers but it has some definitive ones (if there are). So please leave a comment or an answer if you know something.

Comment: There is a Lua backend for IPython at https://github.com/neomantra/lua_ipython_kernel but it has been abandoned.

Comment: Looks like there's also another at [lua - How can I use the torch REPL for debugging? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068607/how-can-i-use-the-torch-repl-for-debugging)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at

- [Luaish](https://github.com/stevedonovan/luaish)
- [luaprompt](http://www.nongnu.org/techne/lua/luaprompt/)
- `QtLua::Console` widget from [QtLua project](http://www.nongnu.org/libqtlua/)
- [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences.html), a full Lua IDE

Comment: thx, I'm just asking for a better interactive shell, not an IDE. the `Local console` of `ZeroBrane Studio` works well, yet not as good as `ipython` in many ways...

Comment: First two are definite. If that doesn't work, second one could be used to quickly wip up a qt-based interactive shell that has tab completion.

Comment: thx a lot, I've tried the windows port of `Luaish`, and it's so so. Since it's hard for me to get one as good as `ipython`, I stopped to toss around and decided to simply use `ilua` and some IDE like ZeroBrane or Scite or Eclipse ;)

Comment: did you try luaprompt?

Comment: I'm on windows lua5.1 and not sure how to build it with that `Makefile`